# how to implement Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in silverlight web application?

Tags: silverlight, web, copy-paste

I need to implement Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in Silverlight web application. I tried catch the event and get the keycodes but when I do System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText("sometext"), it throws a security exception.

Any solution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: As a note to the answer of @PeterPorfy; You could also run it Out Of Browser with elevated trust, but I'm not sure if you're looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `SetText` from a user initiated action. The `keydown` event is such one, so you should call the SetText from a handler attached to that event for example.

This is because silverlight runs in partial trust mode by default, so the clipboard access is restricted to these two event handler. Also, the user will be prompted to allow the access.

Please read more here: [Clipboard Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)